# Producer is not used to produce the Bean as an alternative

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I have a SecurityContext bean which is used for holding information after the user is logged in. This gets injected into my application when running in production. Now, I have written a producer which produces the SecurityContext with some mock data. I have annotated the producer as well as the SecurityBean with the @Alternative annotation and while developing I have the producer class defined in beans.xml as an alternative. I get an exception by deploy:

```
Unsatisfied dependencies for type SecurityContext with qualifiers @Default
```

Here is my SecurityContext:

```
@Named("securityContext")
@SessionScoped
@Alternative
public class SecurityContext implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4438358981780651509L;

    String name;

    public String getName() {return name}

    public void setName(String name) {this.name=name}
}
```

This is my producer:

```
@Named("securityContext")
@Alternative
public class MockSecurityContextProducer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7291628004789622477L;

    @Produces
    @Dependent
    public SecurityContext getSecurityContext() {

        SecurityContext securityContext = new SecurityContext();
        securityContext.setName("Test user");
        return securityContext;

    }
```

I have to mention that all these classes are within a common-lib jar file with a beans.xml inside. I use this jar as a dependency in another project, where the SecurityContext is getting injected, however there is an error by deployment.

Comment: This isn't how alternatives work.  In order for it to be an alternative, you must use an alternate implementation (extends SecurityContext).

Comment: So if I want to use the bean in the production and the producer while developing, there is no way?

Comment: With the way you have things setup, no.  Either both need to be producers, with same scopes and names or both need to be concrete beans with same scopes and names.